# age control 2 for pl/sql

Tags: plsql, triggers

i am trying to find out at what age an employee started working.
if he started under 16 he should report this 'Error when entering the date of birth' mistake. so my trigger is created but my trigger is not working 
I get ever this error: ORA-01422: Exact retrieval returns more than the requested number of lines

i can't find the problem
Here is the code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
ACCEPT Birthday PROMPT ' Pleas give you Date of birth: ' 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_Controll
before INSERT ON  meine_Firma -- Table
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_Berufstart            meine_Firma.Hiredate%TYPE; --Job begin
V_Geburtsdatum          DATE; -- Date of birth
V_Alter                 number:=0; -- AGE
SELECT HIREDATE INTO V_Berufstart FROM meine_Firma;
BEGIN
V_Geburtsdatum:=('&Birthday');  
V_Alter:= Round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(V_Berufstart,V_Geburtsdatum)-2)/12;
IF 16 > V_Alter THEN   
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20201,'Error when entering the date of birth');
END IF;
END;
/
```

SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF

If he under 16 then he may not work
sorry my english is not good (=

Answer (score 2):

You have a much bigger issue in this script than the error you are getting. Even after correcting as @ShaunPeterson suggested it will still fail
, it WILL NOT generate an error it will just not run as you expect. The issue is you failed to understand [substitution variables](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915518) - the use of &name (Specifically here &Birthday.) I'll actually use &Birthday in the following but the discussion applies to ANY/ALL substitution variables.

> people fail to understand why they can't use the "&" substitution
>   variables in their PL/SQL procedures and functions to prompt for input
>   at run time.  This article will hopefully help clarify in your mind
>   what the differences are so that you can understand where and when to
>   use these.
>
> 1. Substitution Variables The clue here is in the name... "substitution". It relates to values being substituted into the code
>      before it is submitted to the database. These substitutions are
>      carried out by the interface being used

The effect of this substitution is the the **line containing the substitution variable is physically rewritten** by the interface replacing %Birthday. In this case if you don't enter a value or the date 2000-05-19 the statement before and after substitution is

- BEFORE:  V_Geburtsdatum:=('&Birthday');
- AFTER:   V_Geburtsdatum:=('');  OR  V_Geburtsdatum:=('2000-05-19');

Either way the after is what the compiler sees; it does NOT see %Birthday at all. Moreover when run the trigger will not prompt for a value. As far as the compiler is concerned it is a hard coded value that will never change. Beyond that a trigger, or any other PLSQL script (stored or anonymous) **never prompts for values**, they are actually incapable of doing so as it is not part of the language. Any prompt is via your interface software not plsql.

I'm going to suggest a way to avoid the trigger altogether.  *Getting on soap box:* Triggers are BAD, they have some usefulness for assigning auto incrementing keys (before 12c),logging, very limited auditing, etc. However, for business rules they should be the option of last resort. *Ok Get off soap box.*

The first thing is to make the columns meine_Firma.Hiredate and meine_Firma.Geburtsdatum NOT null (if not already). If either are NULL you cannot calculate anything with them, the result would be NULL.
Second create a new column age_at_hire (or whatever) as a virtual column then put a check constraint on it. And voila trigger no longer needed. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1c46ae7328d3c8b6945d37c824bf6d28) for demo.
So the proposed change (YES you will probably have to clean up the bad data first):

```
alter table meine_Firma modify 
          ( hiredate     not null
          , Geburtsdatum not null
          ) ;
alter table meine_Firma add                           
          ( age_at_hire integer generated always as (trunc(months_between(hiredate,Geburtsdatum))) virtual
          , constraint check_age_at_hire check (age_at_hire >= 16*12)
          );
```

Anyway, I hope you get an understanding of substitution variables for the future. And learn to avoid triggers. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that specific error is that the below select will select ALL rows from meine_Firma as there is no where clause

```
SELECT HIREDATE INTO V_Berufstart FROM meine_Firma;
```

However because you are in a trigger you do not need to select anything you use the :NEW bind variable. So you can just use

```
V_Berufstart := :NEW.HIREDATE;
```

If this was an update trigger there would be both a :NEW and :OLD bind variable declared so that you can access the OLD and NEW values.  As this is an Insert trigger the :OLD will just be null as there is no old values.

Comment: First of all thank you, but  i have a column 'Geburtsdatum' this is the column of Birthday it is empty. This program should calculate the  age of workers, before stand his Birthday on the table. I get  no errors. he Write the  Birthday of workers on the Table without to calculate. I mean he can't calculate how many years old the person started working.